# $f : A \to B$ s.t. for all $x, y \in A, x R y \iff f(x) S f(y)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Theorem. A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive and transitive if and only if there is a set $B$ with a partial order $S$ and a function $f : A \to B$ such that for all $x, y \in A, x R y \iff   f(x) S f(y)$.

I think the proof is saying that every reflexive and transitive
relation can be mapped into a partial order

**I am trying to prove the following**

**Let $R$ be a partial order on a set $A$. Show that taking $B = A, S = R$, and $f = I_A$ (the
identity function on A) satisfies the Theorem.**

How do i start this proof.  Do I show that $B=A$ is a partial order, $S=R$ is a partial order and $f = I_A$ is a partial order.

**This is what i have so far**

Reflexive: If $x \in A$, then $f(x) = f(x)$ so $xRx$.

Antisymmetric: If $xRy$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ and $f(y) = f(x)$. It follows that $yRx$. so $x = y$.

Transitive: If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ and $f(y) = f(z)$. It follows
that $f(x) = f(z)$ and $xRz$.

I am lost here

Can someone help me on this.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is reflexive and transitive. Then the relation defined by
$$
x\mathrel{R_s}y \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad
x\mathrel{R}y\text{ and }y\mathrel{R} x
$$
is an equivalence relation. The proof is easy.

Consider $B=A/R_s$ and define, for $[x],[y]\in B$ ($[a]$ denotes the equivalence class with respect to $R_s$ of $a\in A$),
$$
[x]\mathrel{S}[y]
\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad
x\mathrel{R}y
$$

Show that this definition is well posed (it doesn't depend on the representatives of the equivalence class) and that $S$ is an order relation on $B$.

Of course the required map $f\colon A\to B$ is the canonical projection on the quotient set.

The converse is an easy verification.

---

Note 1. You can't start from “Let $R$ be a partial order”, because you are not given this hypothesis.

Note 2. The statement in bold face is completely obvious: if $R$ is a partial order, $B=A$ and $R=S$, “$x\mathrel{S}y$ if and only if $x\mathrel{R}y$” *by definition* and $S$ is of course a partial order.

Comment: I am not trying to prove the theorem, i am trying to prove the statement that I highlighted.  In the Statement it is given that Let R be a partial order @egreg

Comment: @AP6 Doesn't this follow from the general proof? In the case when $R$ is a partial order, $R_s$ is the identity relation, so $A/R_s$ is essentially the same as $A$. More easily, if $B=A$ and $S=R$, there's *nothing* to prove.

Comment: OHH okay got it thanks @egreg